# Cannot read parquet using PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

I'm currently writing a program in PySpark, which involves writing dataframe to parquet using a loop. New data is appended to the parquet in each cycle. The parquet is stored in S3 bucket.

I was able to write the parquet, but when I load the parquet to a dataframe, and try to read it using

```
df.take(5)
```

I encounter the following error message

```
An error occurred while calling o461.collectToPython.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 32.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 32.0 (TID 57, ip-10-0-2-219.ec2.internal, executor 5): 
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: org.apache.parquet.column.values.dictionary.PlainValuesDictionary$PlainBinaryDictionary
...
```

However, I can run the following commands on the dataframe:

```
df.count()
df.printSchema()
```

Any idea why this error occurs?

Comment: Can you please share your file if that's okay so that i can try replicating the issue at my end? Also, would like to know how many partitions you are creating and please also check and confirm whether the schema of all the parquet files generated are same. If they are different, you know the cause of the issue already.

Comment: Most likely multiple parquet files that you write end up having different schema. See similar jira issues, for example https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17557